# How to formulate a second order exponential Runge-Kutta using Butcher's tableaux

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods, nonlinear-dynamics

**The Problem**

I have been struggling to determine the coefficients $b_i$ and $a_{ij}$ for a second order exponential Runge-Kutta scheme, for which I am provided with the generic formulation as well as Butcher's tableaux. For more context, this scheme is explained [here](https://na.math.kit.edu/download/papers/acta-final.pdf) (pg. 221, 226).

The differential equation is of the form:
\begin{equation}
u'(t) + Au(t) = g(u(t)), \quad u(0) = u_0
\end{equation}

The exponential RK scheme generic formulas are given as:

\begin{align}
u_{n+1} & = u_n + h_n\sum^s_{i=1}b_i(-h_nA)(G_{ni}-Au_n) \\
U_{ni} & = u_n + h_n\sum^s_{j=1}a_{ij}(-h_nA)(G_{nj}-Au_n) \\
G_{nj} & = g(U_{nj})
\end{align}

The Butcher's tableaux for the second order method I want to use is given as:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c | c c}
0 & & \\
c_2 & c_2\phi_{1,2} & \\ \hline
& \phi_1 - \frac{1}{c_2}\phi_2 & \frac{1}{c_2}\phi_2 &
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $\phi_{1,2},\,\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are known functions of $h_nA$.

**Attempt**

From the above, by observation I can deduce the following:

\begin{align}
u_{n+1} & = u_n + h_n\left[ b_1(-h_nA)(G_{n1}-Au_n) + b_2(-h_nA)(G_{n2}-Au_n) \right]\\
U_{n1} & = u_n,\quad\text{hence}\quad G_{n1} = g(u_n) \\
U_{n2} & = u_n + h_n\left[a_{2,1}(-h_nA)(G_{n1}-Au_n) \right], \quad\text{hence}\quad G_{n2} = g(U_{n2}) \\
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
a_{2,1}(-h_nA) & = c_2\phi_{1,2} \\
b_1(-h_nA) & = \phi_1 - \frac{1}{c_2}\phi_2 \\
b_2(-h_nA) & = \frac{1}{c_2}\phi_2 
\end{align}

However, when using the above formulation I attempt to solve a very simple differential equation, for which the exponential Euler scheme was able to solve, the exponential RK is extremely unstable and eventually diverges. Moreover, if I increase $c_2$ to some absurdly large number (e.g. 100), the exponential RK as I formulated above, approximates the exponential Euler scheme which does not seem to make sense. So my only conclusion is that I am formulating the RK scheme in a wrong way.